# "Maybe answered questions" box on "Ask Question" page is much more useful than "Search Q&A"

Tags: discussion, asking-questions, search

I often find that "*Search Q&A*" is quite useless when I want to find a question or something related to it. But I've also noticed that when I'm about to ask a question, the "*Questions that may already have your answer*" box has many relevant results.

For example, see this search: [failure of uniqueness Cauchy problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?tab=relevance&q=failure%20of%20uniqueness%20cauchy%20problem). It gives me exactly zero results. Now if you paste the same request into [Ask Question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) title box, you'll get lots of results (including the one I was initially looking for).

So, is it really by design? Does *Search Q&A* have some different use than what I supposed it does? Wouldn't it be a good idea to at least make the duplicate-finding functionality easier to find since it works better at finding questions by a topic given in free form?

Comment: Good search functionality is something SE is really lacking IMO.  I have completely abandoned the "Search Q&A" box for general searches, I now always use the Ask Question button to search.  Have you considered posting this on global meta?  It may get a better answer there.

Comment: See also [Announcing a third-party search engine for Math StackExchange](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/24978/announcing-a-third-party-search-engine-for-math-stackexchange) which often times returns more relevant hits than the built-in search (or the `related` list for a posted question on the RHS, for that matter).

Comment: @PGmath I've checked now, and there appears to already exist [a question on main Meta](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/20432/related-questions-in-ask-question-page-is-better-than-search-tool), with multiple duplicates. But it seems to have not very useful answers... Should I make yet another duplicate, comparing concrete request given to different engines as is done here?

Comment: The Search Q&A tool is a narrow/conservative interpreter of your terms.  If you remove "failure of" from the proposed search, [one gets 238 results](http://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=uniqueness+cauchy+problem).  So my belief is that the Ask Question suggestions are being produced by the same site-specific search, but using subsetting of words in the title.  Something similar seems to drive the Related links in the sidebar, where searches make additional use of the `[tag]` information.