# Feature request:- Make the search bar support latex

Tags: feature-request, mathjax, search

For instance consider $\int_0^1 e^{x^2-x}dx$. before asking for help with a certain aspect of this question, I attempted to search for it on MSE. However, this is what I got.[image]

The worst part is how the search bar is interpreting my LaTex code.(ex2-x).

I could ask the question, but I run the risk of it being closed, hence increasing the chance me being banned.

Therefore, I would like to request for LaTeX support in the search bar.

Comment: Have you tried approach0.xyz ? It searches math.stackexchange, and Art of Problem Solving, and supports TeX.

Comment: never heard of that, I'l try it. Thanks!

Comment: To add to the previous comment, there is this FAQ post: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The built-in search (as it currently works) is probably not optimal for finding a specific mathematical expression. But still, it can be used *sometimes*.

For example, I could try to:

- [search for int "e^{x^2-x}"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=int+%22e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7D%22)
- [search for int "e^{x^2-x}dx"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=int+%22e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7Ddx%22)
- I could combine the expression ["e^{x^2-x}dx"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bintegration%5D+%22e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7Ddx%22) or ["e^{x^2-x}"](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=%5Bintegration%5D+%22e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7D%22) with the tag [integration](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/integration).

Notice that I have used quotation marks to search for a specific expression.

The results are closer - but far from great. The search engine ignores special symbols. And if there is a post about the same integral, but the variable is denoted by $t$ rather than $x$, I won't find it from this search.

---

There are various search engines which are suitable for mathematical formulas, see the FAQ post: [How to search on this site?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/29265) (This post is mentioned [in the help center](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) - it was added based on this feature request: [Should we add external searches in some help pages about search?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/27421))

For example, at the moment, both ApproachZero and SearchOnMath can be used to find posts on this site. (In ApproachZero you can even search for posts in a specific tag.)

You can use your integral to test them a bit:

- Searching for $\int_0^1 e^{x^2-x}dx$ in [ApproachZero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint_0%5E1%20e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7Ddx%24&p=1) and [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Cint_0%5E1%20e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7Ddx%7D%24)
- Searching for $\int e^{x^2-x}dx$ in [ApproachZero](https://approach0.xyz/search/?q=OR%20content%3A%24%5Cint%20e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7Ddx%24&p=1) and [SearchOnMath](https://www.searchonmath.com/result?query=%24%7B%5Cint%20e%5E%7Bx%5E2-x%7Ddx%7D%24)

And there are certainly various other variation you could try.

Comment: Thank you for he help!