# Update the Help Center article on searching to mention the in:saves operator in place of the inbookmarks:mine operator

Tags: bug, search, help-center, saves

The Help Center article titled ["How do I search?"](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/searching) needs to be updated to mention the `in:saves` operator in place of the deprecated `inbookmarks:mine` operator.

After "bookmarks" changed to ["saves"](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/382019/bookmarks-have-evolved-into-saves), the Help Center article on searching was updated everywhere (compare the first link with the corresponding Help Center article at [Meta SE](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/searching), for instance) to mention the `in:saves` operator in place of the `inbookmarks:mine` operator. However, this change didn't get pushed to our site's Help Center, since that page was previously edited following this request: [Should we add external searches in some help pages about search?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27421/should-we-add-external-searches-in-some-help-pages-about-search).

So, I request that this Help Center article be updated by our site moderators with the following changes, so that it matches the version at Meta SE:

- In the section "User Operators", the second bullet point should read:

  > `in:saves` returns posts that you have [saved](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/saves)

  As copyable text:

  ```
  `in:saves` returns posts that you have [saved](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/saves)
  ```
- In the same section, the third bullet point can also be updated as follows:

  > `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags that you are watching. (If you don't have any watched tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, [update your watched tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current).)

  As copyable text:

  ```
  `intags:mine` returns only posts that appear in tags that you are watching. (If you don't have any watched tags, this operator does nothing. For better results, [update your watched tags](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/tag-notifications/current).)
  ```